# When forwarding data via python how do I space out the data strings?

Tags: python, forwarding

I have a positioning system that sends the data from a tag it's tracking to a specific port, 8787. I have a Python script that then takes that data string and forwards it to a specific port for my database, 8011. There are three tags that send data. The positioning system is hard coded to send to port 8787 and the database is Oracle and only takes in data from port 8011 hence the need for the forwarding of the data.

Here is the string of data each tag sends (it's always in this format):

> {"id":"0xDECA38303180234E","timestamp":1450653835.723,"msgid":6825,"coordinates":{"x":4.160,"y":2.368,"z":-0.604,"heading":0.000,"pqf":65},"meas":[{"anchor":"0xDECA323031300FBF","dist":4.343,"tqf":64,"rssi":-48},{"anchor":"0xDECA323030901DE2","dist":0.779,"tqf":32,"rssi":-46},{"anchor":"0xDECA313032901F24","dist":1.223,"tqf":32,"rssi":-44},{"anchor":"0xDECA353034301E99","dist":4.929,"tqf":32,"rssi":-46}]}

When it's one tag streaming data the python script reads each string separately then forwards each data string one at a time. When there are two or more tags the python script groups the incoming data strings and sends them together which causes errors with the database as it's set up to accept a specific format. I can print them separately via a modified print command, but I can't forward each data string separately.

Here is the Python script that forwards the data:

```
import socket
from pip._vendor import requests
import json
import time


port = 8787
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("", port))
print ("waiting on port:", port)

while 1:
#var_data = s.recvfrom(1024)
    var_headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    var_data, addr = s.recvfrom(16029)
    print (var_data)
    var_data_json = json.dumps(var_data) #@UndefinedVariable
    #print (var_data_json)

    response = requests.post('http://localhost:8011/SB_PositionLocatingService/PositionLocatingProxyService', data=var_data, headers=var_headers)
```

I tried the timer function with no success. Any help would be most appreciative. Thanks
Brian

Here is how the python streams the data from one tag and it works perfectly:

```
{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.477,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.478,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.479,
```

From two tags it fails since it's sent as one:

```
{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.477,
{"id":"0xDECA38303180235F","timestamp":1451680331.478,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.478,
{"id":"0xDECA38303180235F","timestamp":1451680331.479,
```

From three tags fails since it's sent as one:

```
{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.477,
{"id":"0xDECA38303180235F","timestamp":1451680331.478,
{"id":"0xDECA38303180234E","timestamp":1451680331.479,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.478,
{"id":"0xDECA38303180235F","timestamp":1451680331.479,
{"id":"0xDECA38303180234E","timestamp":1451680331.480,
```

Here is what I'm trying for with two and three tags so it's spaced just like it is with one tag:

```
{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.477,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180235F","timestamp":1451680331.478,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180234E","timestamp":1451680331.479,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.478,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180235F","timestamp":1451680331.479,

{"id":"0xDECA38303180234E","timestamp":1451680331.480,
```

Comment: Have you tried parsing the JSON object before you send it, then using a for loop to send the post request, generating a new JSON string from the parsed object? That way you could be certain that each incoming object equates to one HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Here is what I tried for parsing it.  



    `var_data_json = json.dumps(var_data)
     # @UndefinedVariable


     print (var_data_json)`  



The results is one datastring regardless of how many sources are streaming and it doesn't space it out like it does in the updated post of one tag streaming. Am I missing something? It also add double quotes on both ends of the string.

Comment: just looking at this now - I'm assuming that each `{"id":"0xDECA38303180234D","timestamp":1451680331.477,` continues as per the original post?

Comment: Brian Bowles - two problems: the first is that to send the data using `json.dumps()` you first need to parse it using `json.load()` - i.e. `my_data = json.load(string_from_sensor); http_payload = json.dumps(my_data);` however, this only works if `string_from_sensor` comes only from one sensor. At the moment, you just have lots of characters coming at you from multiple sensors, so you need a way of knowing when one stops and another begins. I'll work on a code and post it below, but I won't be able to test it so it may be buggy...

Answer (score 0):

I've had a quick go at it, code below. The problem was that you had no way of knowing when one reading ended and the other began. I've replaced your loop with one that will continually add the input string to a variable, then continually check that variable for a complete reading. When it encounters a complete reading, it'll forward it on, leaving the remaining string to be added to, and then parsed in the next iteration.

**Watch out for...**

- Any change whatsoever to your data structure: if the [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) no longer works, it'll stop forwarding on any data, and just make a massive string until you eventually run out of memory
- Any problems forwarding your data on (i.e., if your listening server breaks, this code will just carry on running)
- Sensors sending readings simultaneously and getting mixed together, so that if one sensor said "hello" and the other "bonjour", you'll get the string "h**b**e**o**l**n**l**j**o**our**", which would break this script. In that case, you'll need to start assigning individual ports to each sensor.

Hope this helps

```
# author: Brian Bowles
# edited by: Dom Weldon, London, 05 Jan 2015

# load deps
import socket
from pip._vendor import requests
import json
import re # note: replaced time with re (regular expressions, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

# adjustable settings
port_listen                         =   8787
port_forward                        =   8011
forwarding_url                      =   "http://localhost:{0}/SB_PositionLocatingService/PositionLocatingProxyService".format(port_forward)
forwarding_headers                  =   {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

# start listening on port
s                                   = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("", port))
print ("waiting on port:", port)

# We have strings being fired at us from sensors, we need to pick out individual
# chunks of JSON data then forward them on using a POST request. First, let's 
# process the data every 1024 bytes.
while var_data = s.recvfrom(1024)
    # and add each 1024 byte chunk to a big string of all the data we receive.
    all_input_string                +=  var_data

    # an individual sensor sends data in the format below. 
    '''
    {
      "id": "0xDECA38303180234E",
      "timestamp": 1450653835.723,
      "msgid": 6825,
      "coordinates": {
        "x": 4.16,
        "y": 2.368,
        "z": -0.604,
        "heading": 0,
        "pqf": 65
      },
      "meas": [
        {
          "anchor": "0xDECA323031300FBF",
          "dist": 4.343,
          "tqf": 64,
          "rssi": -48
        },
        {
          "anchor": "0xDECA323030901DE2",
          "dist": 0.779,
          "tqf": 32,
          "rssi": -46
        },
        {
          "anchor": "0xDECA313032901F24",
          "dist": 1.223,
          "tqf": 32,
          "rssi": -44
        },
        {
          "anchor": "0xDECA353034301E99",
          "dist": 4.929,
          "tqf": 32,
          "rssi": -46
        }
      ]
    }
    '''

    # does it look like we have one *complete* sensor output contained within
    # our big string? use a regex (albeit a lazy one) to find out
    # (the regex looks for the string "}]}"" found only at the end of one sensor
    # reading then returns two strings: the text before it, and the text after
    # it).
    match                           =   re.match('([^\}\]\}]+)(\}\]\})(.*)', all_input_string)
    if (match):
        # yes, pick it out of the string and send it on, save the remainder
        # of the string for the next pass through
        input_components            =   match.groups()
        reading_to_send             =   input_components[0] + input_components[1] # the first complete reading
        all_input_string            =   input_components[2] # the remainder of the string

        # send off the complete reading 
        print("Received the following data to forward on: {0}".format(reading_to_send))
        response                    =   requests.post(forwarding_port, data=reading_to_send, headers=forwarding_headers)
        print("Forwarded response. Response code: {0}".format(response.status_code))
```

Comment: p.s. - I haven't tested this code, so sorry if it's buggy. It's also got lots of comments to help explain what I've done!